# How to get 0.000001 instead of 1e-06?

Tags: python, math, numbers, mathematical-optimization, division

I want to print the whole number instead of 1e-06

```
number = 1

result = number/1000000

print(result)
```

Please help whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following by using `format`:

```
number = 1
result = number/1000000
print('{0:.6f}'.format(result))
```

Output:

```
0.000001
```

Comment: Why not just `{:f}`?

Comment: Could also use an f-string... `print(f'{result:.6f}')`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, this is also possible. But maybe this helps the OP to see how to use the formatting feature of format with decimal number.

Comment: Just wanting to add, and this may be dependent on Python version, but `number` and `1000000` need to be declared as `float` on 2.7 for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

`output = f"{num:.9f}"`

you can replace `9` with the amount of numbers you have after the decimal point in your number.

and also you will need to define your variable to `float` to order it will work.